# How do I delete photos from JUST my iPhone 6s when using iCloud Photo Library?

Tags: ios, icloud, photos.app

Whenever I got to delete a photo, it says "This photo will be deleted from iCloud Photo Library on all your devices." I don't want it deleted from my iCloud Photo Library, only my iPhone 6s. What I want to do is import photos and videos from my iPhone to my MacBook Pro and then delete them from my iPhone. If I import those photos and videos to my Mac and then delete them from my iPhone (ignoring the warning) will they also be deleted from my Mac?

Comment: Could you just turn off iCloud Photo Library for the phone and leave it on for the Mac?

Comment: @kal-al I guess I could, but I'd rather use iCloud Photo Library on all my Apple products, if possible

Comment: grgarside's answer is correct. If you'd like similar functionality without using space on your phone, try a service like Google Photos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iCloud Photo Library's purpose is to unify the photo libraries across your devices. If you wish your devices to maintain separate libraries, you need to disable iCloud Photo Library.

Comment: Okay, that was what was confusing me.